# Как проверить, что изображение корректное?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Есть скрипт, который копирует изображение по протоколу http . Копирование осуществляется функцией `copy`

Столкнулись с тем, что время от времени изображение копируется, но не полностью. 
Не полностью - это значит что, например, если посмотреть скопированное изображение в браузере, то оно будет показано наполовину.

Я пробовал проверить изображение на валидность через `getimagesize`, но эта функция показывает, что все в порядке. То есть, заголовок файла в порядке.

Такое ощущение, что удаленный сервер иногда просто прерывает соединение, поэтому первая часть файла корректная, со всеми заголовками, а потом файл неожиданно прекращается.

Мы переписываемся с админом удаленного сервера, но пока безрезультатно, он утверждает что сервер отдает файл полностью, без ошибок.

Но по факту изображения сохраняются некорректно.

Как можно средствами пхп проверить, что файл скопировано полностью, без ошибок? Что файл - валидное изображение?

Исходный файл корректный 100%, это видно в том же браузере, если посмотреть на файл-источник .

Сложность в том, что это происходит регулярно, но редко. Когда я проверяю работу скрипта глазами, из примерно 30-ти запусков изображение загрузилось некорректно один раз. То есть возможности отладки сильно ограничены, к сожалению.

И есть несколько десятков тысяч файлов, часть из которых некорректные. Как их найти?

Спасибо.

Comment: результат работы функции проверяете? Если 30 раз открыть исходную картинку с удаленного сервера в браузере (без кэширования), то она всегда корректная?

Comment: Сравнить что в `Content-Length` и реальности после скачивания. Не совпало - перезагрузить.

Comment: В запущенных случаях юзать что-то типа [`crc32`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.crc32.php).

Answer (score 0):

Выяснил, что корректность картинки можно проверить через imagecopyresampled. Если false - то с изображением что-то не так.

Спасибо.

Comment: Но проверка content-length или crc32 гораздо более адекватные вещи

Comment: А как именно можно проверить? Я так понимаю, что crc32 выдает контрольную сумму файла - с чем ее сравнивать?

Comment: Спросить crc32 у того, кто отдаёт вам изображение, и сравнить с вашим :) Если отдавать crc32 никто не хочет, то хотя бы content-length всегда должен быть